# How to pass the WebDriver instance to other Class in Selenium/Java/TestNG?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have created 2 classes in 2 packages under one project and calling one method of class A into class B by creating object of class but it is giving me null pointer exception below is the code can any one help on this:

---

```
package Login;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import Repository.Objects;

// import Repository.Objects;

public class Loginasa {


    public static  WebDriver driver;
     String baseUrl;

     @BeforeSuite
     public void setUp() throws Exception 
     {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver =new ChromeDriver();
        baseUrl= "http://10.7.30.135:9090/xGLinear/login.html";
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     }



    @Test 
     public void Newlogin() throws Exception 
     {
     // driver.get(baseUrl);

    driver.findElement(By.id(Objects.Username)).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id(Objects.Username)).sendKeys("ASA");
    driver.findElement(By.id(Objects.Password)).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id(Objects.Password)).sendKeys("Abcd1234");
    driver.findElement(By.id(Objects.loginbtn)).click();
    Thread.sleep(20000);
     }

    @AfterTest
      public void tearDown() throws Exception 
     {
        driver.quit();
        System.out.println("Browser Launch");
   }





}
```

---

Another is:

```
package Commonmethods;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import Login.Loginasa;

public class CreateOrderline  {

    public static  WebDriver driver;
    String baseUrl;

     @BeforeTest
     public void setUp() throws Exception 
     {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver =new ChromeDriver();
        baseUrl= "http://10.7.30.135:9090/xGLinear/login.html";
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);


     }

    @Test 
     public void Orderline () throws Exception 
     {
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        Loginasa ASA= new Loginasa();
        System.out.println("Browser Launch");
         ASA.Newlogin();

     }

         @AfterTest
          public void tearDown() throws Exception 
         {
            driver.quit();
            System.out.println("Browser Launch");
       }
     }
```

---

Giving Error: NULL Pointer Exception............

Comment: Paste your error also

Comment: Please provide your error log or stacktrace so we can identify error line.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking, Please add some more details about your question and queries.

Comment: @Rashmi Could you please provide the code which you write in test-ng file. because as per my understanding your webdriver session get closed that why you get the null pointer execution

Comment: What IDE are you using to build your tests? I would like to suggest better ways to debug nullpointer exceptions like this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's good design to call one test from another fixture. Had problems with that in the past. You might consider using [Page Objects](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/PageObjects)

Anyhow, in your case it looks like you have a NullPointerException because ASA.setUp() isn't called before calling ASA.NewLogin() when the setup method of the referring class is called.

Though it's C# you can find a working proposal of how to organize your test code [here](https://github.com/mathume/SeleniumPOC).

Comment: The problem is that the setup method from Loginasa won't be called automatically from the CreateOrderOnline instance as it's _another test suite_  Maybe if CreateOrderOnline inherited from Loginasa the setup method would be visible to the test runner from a CreateOrderOnline instance.

Comment: @BharatMane user1130 is right, the setUp() is not called for instantiated class in your tests. So when you use the "new" keyword the setUp() is not called.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use two instances of browser. Just specify one instance and you can use the same instance in a project. You can call the browser object by specifying the classname.objectname. ie,

```
CreateOrderline.driver.findElement(By.id(Objects.Username)).clear();
CreateOrderline.driver.findElement(By.id(Objects.Username)).sendKeys("ASA");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the driver when creating the `Loginasa` instance:

```
Loginasa ASA= new Loginasa(driver);
```

Then you also need to add [a constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) to the Loginasa class to pass the driver:

```
public class Loginasa {
  public static  WebDriver driver;
  public Loginasa(passedDriver) {
    driver = passedDriver;
  }
}
```

Now can you remove the `setUp()` function from the `Loginasa` class, this one is useless anyways cause it is not called by TestNG for that test. TestNG only calls the `setUp()` of classes for which it runs the test, not classes used by the test. This is also the reason you get a NullPointer exception, the class has an empty `driver` property when you call `ASA.Newlogin()`. Also remove all the other annotations from `Loginasa`. You shouldn't be using a test-class as a class you are going to instantiate from within another test.

I would have a look at the [Page Object Model](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html) for TestNG: http://www.ontestautomation.com/using-the-page-object-model-pattern-in-selenium-testng-tests/

Also have a look at how you can start debugging NullPointer exceptions yourself:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17871825/a-good-way-to-debug-nullpointerexception